# scheduled task share permissions

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, network-share, scheduled-task

I would like to know if there is a way I can share :

```
\\server\Scheduled Tasks
```

On server 2003 with normal users, cause as far as I can tell it seems only administrators can see this share, is there anyway I can change this share's permission and add users or groups?

I know I can change permission on the jobs themselves, but normal users don't see the folder at all, so they cant access the jobs...

Thank You.

Comment: I take it this is for read only permissions? having write permission would be a bad mooooove.

Answer (score 1):

I added bold to some obvious parts.

> **By default, to schedule a task, you must be a member of the Administrators, Backup Operators, or Server Operators group on the local computer.** By default, when creating a scheduled task, you cannot enter a user who belongs to a group that has more rights than the group you belong to. For example, if you are a member of the Backup Operators group on the local computer, you cannot specify a member of the Administrators group when creating a scheduled task. However, a member of the Administrators group can enable a member of any group to create or modify scheduled tasks, by using the cacls command to modify the discretionary access control list (DACL) of the Tasks folder. By default, the Tasks folder is located in the \Windows folder on the hard drive of the local computer, for example C:\Windows\Tasks. For more information about using cacls, see Cacls. For more information about groups, see Default local groups and Default groups. [0]

[0] ["Task Scheduler and security" on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785125%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As long as there isn't a $ at the end of the share, they should be able to at least see it.
As far as permissions go, right click on the local folder on your server. You'll want to make sure that everyone has full control in the share tab, and lock it down with what ever NTFS user/group permissions you want to have it in the Permissions tab.

Comment: Hi, the thing about the "Scheduled Tasks" folder is that it is somehow different from any other file. Only local administrators can see the share and when you view the real folder's (c:\windows\tasks) properties there is not sharing tab...

Comment: What end result are you looking for? Are you wanting to run scheduled tasks on all your PCs from this location? Copy the job to all your PCs? 
There's different ways of doing this besides just sharing out that share, which I believe is a protected file.
For instance, if you have a windows 2008, Vista, or Windows 7 computer. You can connect to the server's active directory with that, and use it's built in group policy to manage all tasks from any OU that you want.